# How to quickly toggle subdivision preview like Maya?

Tags: modeling

[image]

In maya, you can quickly toggle a subdivision preview by pressing the *1* and *3* keys on the keyboard.

In blender, you are able to accomplish something almost identical by using *Ctrl + 1,2,3,4,5...0* which toggles the subdivision level to *1,2,3,4,5,...0*

The issue that I am having is that in order to switch back from subdivision view to standard view, I have to press *Ctrl + 0* which is all the way on the other side of my keyboard.

This is extremely tedious and slow.

Is there a blender addon which makes this process slightly easier?

Is there a better way to bind the keys to accomplish this workflow?

Comment: You could just use a macro to switch between both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Keymap** change it or add a new one.
But this one only change the viewport level.

[image]

If you want to change the render level, you can do a operator.
Here is a addon example to do that.

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Quick Subidivion Set",
    "author" : "X Y",
    "version" : (1, 0),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "View3d > Tool",
    "warning" : "",
    "description" : "",
    "category" : "Mesh",
}

import bpy
from bpy.utils import register_class
from bpy.utils import unregister_class

def change_rend(level):
    try:
        mds = bpy.context.object.modifiers
        for md in mds:
            if md.type == 'SUBSURF':
                md.render_levels = level
    except:
        pass

class SUBSET1(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.subset1_operator"
    bl_label = "Operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=1)
        change_rend(1)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SUBSET2(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.subset2_operator"
    bl_label = "Operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=2)
        change_rend(2)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SUBSET3(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.subset3_operator"
    bl_label = "Operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=3)
        change_rend(3)
        return {'FINISHED'}



addon_keymaps = []
def register():
    register_class(SUBSET1)
    register_class(SUBSET2)
    register_class(SUBSET3)

    # Add the hotkey
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("view3d.subset1_operator", type='ONE', value='PRESS')
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("view3d.subset2_operator", type='TWO', value='PRESS')
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("view3d.subset3_operator", type='THREE', value='PRESS')
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))


def unregister():
    unregister_class(SUBSET1)
    unregister_class(SUBSET2)
    unregister_class(SUBSET3)

    # Remove the hotkey
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Save to .py file and install.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Both the 'Show in Viewport' (cyan, below)  and the 'Show in Edit Mode' (green, below) settings for the *Subdivision* modifier can be given <kbd>Q</kbd> quick-menu entries, and assigned keyboard shortcuts, by right-clicking them.

[image]

Here the shipped add-on 'Modifier Tools' is also enabled and assigned to a quick-menu item, so the visibility of all the modifiers can set simultaneously, from the quick menu...

[image]

... above, the assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> for 'Show in Viewport' shortcut is illustrated in Object and Edit mode. The shortcut is ***modifier-name dependent***, so will not affect other modifiers, but will also screw up if you change the name of the *Subdivision* modifier of interest.